# Gerar números com base no índice no array

Tags: java

Preciso gerar números aleatórios dentro de um intervalo... até ai tudo bem, porém, preciso fazer isso para cada posição do array, por exemplo, na posição 1 do meu array, deverão ser inseridos números aleatórios num intervalo 10 à 20, na posição 2, números aleatórios num intervalo 30 à 40 e assim sucessivamente. A posição inicial e a final, já estarão preenchidas.

-- Trecho do código --

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int v[] = new int[capacity];

    v[0] = 0;
    v[capacity - 1] = 15;

    for (int i = 1; i < v.length - 1; i++) {
        switch (i) {
        case 1:
            v[i] = 1 + r.nextInt(2);
            break;
        case 2:
            v[i] = 4 + r.nextInt(3);
            break;
        case 3:
            v[i] = 8 + r.nextInt(3);
            break;
        case 4:
            v[i] = 12 + r.nextInt(2);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: O método `nextInt` da classe `Random` já lhe permite especificar um limite superior. Se somar a algo dá um limite superior e inferior. Aproveite e coloque o código que está a utilizar para o problema, para que a comunidade lhe consiga ajudar na duvida que tem.

Comment: Perfeito Isac... o problema é que recebo o tamanho do array por parâmetro, no exemplo acima, trabalho com um de 6 posições, mas terei de manipular de 5 e 8 posições também...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pretende criar aleatórios em gamas de `20` valores pode faze-lo com um `for` em vez de manualmente como está a fazer.

Sim, porque apesar de estar a utilizar um `for` o preenchimento que tem é manual, pois avalia os indices específicos:

```
for (int i...){
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
```

Logo seria equivalente, e mais claro fazer:

```
v[1] = 1 + r.nextInt(2);
v[2] = 4 + r.nextInt(3);
v[3] = 8 + r.nextInt(3);
v[4] = 12 + r.nextInt(2);
```

Generalizando, ter um `for` e dentro um `switch` baseado na variável do `for` é sempre mau principio.

Para resolver o problema pode fazer assim:

```
for (int i = 1, base = 10; i < v.length - 1; i++, base += 20) {
    v[i] = base + r.nextInt(11); //11 pois o ultimo índice é exclusive
}
```

Repare que adicionei a variável base que define a base do aleatório e que vai andando de `20` em `20` com começo no `10`.

Para perceber melhor como o aleatório está a ser gerado podemos analisar o primeiro caso. Base `10` `+` valor aleatório entre `0` e `10` dá um valor entre `10` e `20`. O mesmo se aplica para os restantes elementos.

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/638os2)

Comment: Isac, muito obrigado!
Funcionou! E sim, estava horrível aquele case dentro do for... valeu!!!